# Add excel vba code to button using c#

Tags: c#, excel, button, vba

I have a question about creating excel button and adding vba code function on it. I have created a button and module code but don't know how to make relation between them. Can anyone show me how?

my code for Button:

```
 Excel.Shape btn = xlWorkSheet5.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.CommandButton.1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 300, 10, 150, 22);

 Excel.OLEObject sheetBtn = (Excel.OLEObject)xlWorkSheet5.OLEObjects(btn.Name);
            sheetBtn.Object.GetType().InvokeMember("Caption", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, sheetBtn.Object, new object[] { "Calculate Bus Load" });
```

and code for module:

```
 String sCode = "Sub main()\r\n" +
                "   MsgBox \"Hello world\"\r\n" +
                "end Sub";

 VBA.VBComponent oModule = xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            oModule.Name = "Module1";
            oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);

            xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(1).CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. Perhaps you could later update your question with the final answer to benefit anyone like you and me. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have searched in Internet but didn't find anything usefull, so i cleared my mind and focused once more with c# help and I found an answer how to do it properly.

My Code:

```
String updateBT "...// macro code for button";   
VBA.VBComponent oModule1 = xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
oModule1.Name = "Update";
oModule1.CodeModule.AddFromString(updateBT);

Excel.Shape btn2 = xlWorkSheet1.Shapes.AddFormControl(Excel.XlFormControl.xlButtonControl, 150, 5, 150, 22);
btn2.Name = "Update";
btn2.OnAction = "... // name of your macro code";
btn2.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "... // Button name";
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need the intermediate `call` to code/macro module from the `button` when you `click` on the button. So the code gets triggered and does what you want it to do.

In usual manner, for e.g.

- we add a button in Excel Sheet
- choose `on_click` event
- add a code like `call mySub`

You need to do that within C#.

Please adjust for your module and control names. Here is a sample.

```
//Within your above code add,

sheetBtn.Click += new MSForms.CommandButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(sheetBtn_Click);

}

//button click event triggers

void sheetBtn_Click()
{
     call subMain
     // try a test using : MessageBox.Show("button test!");  
}
```

** [PLEASE TRY THIS TUTORIAL OUT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12257/Build-Your-Own-Add-in-For-Microsoft-Office-Using-N) It has pretty much what you need.

As per the subject on just invoking a sheet sub or module sub written in Excel from C#, you may use `run macro` method.

```
//instead of this.application, you call refer to the Excel app object
this.Application.Run("yourMacroName",missing,missing........)
```

[Reference:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/030b8d66-7ec8-44b4-a98d-6ebf0631e69a)

Comment: Something like `  MSForms.CommandButton cmdButton = sheetBtn.Object;

                cmdButton.Click += new MSForms.CommandButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(cmdButton_Click);` and then ` void cmdButton_Click()
        {
            
                

        }` ? but what should i write in cmdbutton_click?

Comment: Do you have the freedom to use a already created button in Excel? Where that button event already has the `call subMain` in Excel?

Comment: hmm i don't think so, how can i active it?